# Project war file does not occur in dist folder

Tags: spring, hibernate, netbeans, war

I run `clean and build` in `netbeans` web project.Past ,the war file was created in the dist folder. However I do same thing, but it was not created in dist folder. How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs as it produces when you do clean and build using netbeans.It might show you the contexts and some paths it uses for creating a war.May be some of them might be missing.If it still does not help 
try this

1. Stop the server.
2. Do clean and build and it will produce the war file now.
3. check the logs again.